# Yii2 assets clear cache

Tags: php, assets, yii2

Everytime I update my css or js files in infoweb\menu\module\assets, I have to empty the backend\web\assets folder
is there a way to automatically clear the assets cache?

Comment: Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723515/why-by-every-refreshing-page-cache-reload-anew/37729758#37729758

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this in your view:

```
use vendor\myVendorName\myPackageName\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

Add this in your config:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'linkAssets' => true,
    ], 
]
```

Empty assets folder, and refresh, done

Comment: Are there any drawbacks with this? Why is this not default?

Comment: something with 'option followsymlinks' not being a default setting on servers I think: http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-publishing

Comment: Okay. One other thing if you can answer this: When is a new assets sub folder (like '8f02e6b5') gets created? Over the time I've got over 20 such folders. And I don't know when they get created. It is not with each change in a JS file as it seems to me.

Comment: I think yii creates an asset folder for every asset bundle you register in your views, inside the folder is your js file that gets updated every time you make a change (not if you use linkassets => true but you get the point)

Comment: Note: when using linkAssets you can also use chrome's 'add folder to workplace' and change your js library in the browser while debugging it.

Answer (score 18):

there is additional property as

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
       ...;
       ...;
       ...;
       $config['components']['assetManager']['forceCopy'] = true;
       ...;
       ...;
 }
```

to publish files even there are published before

Comment: Why would'nt people use gulp or grunt, with a package manager like bower or npm...?

its just so much easier....

Comment: because this is built in functionality of Yii2 - AssetsBundle.

Comment: you can use bower in yii in combination with the asset manager

Comment: [forceCopy](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$forceCopy-detail) is not recommended in production as it is very expensive (see note at [AssetManager::publish()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#publish%28%29-detail)).

Comment: That's correct @robsch, that's why JustSamter's answer proposed enabling forceCopy only for the dev environment.

Comment: Where to write it so it could be applicable throughout the project?

Answer (score 13):

If you enviroment is production I recommend to use [Cache Busting](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#cache-busting) :

```
return [
 // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'appendTimestamp' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

for more information about assets, read the [Assets Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Answer (score 9):

If you are developing your own plugin, you can force publish assets per bundle
(note: $sourcePath should be set)

```
<?php
   namespace app\components\forms\redactorAssets;

   use yii\web\AssetBundle;

   class RedactorCutAsset extends AssetBundle {
      public $sourcePath = '@app/components/forms/redactorAssets/assets';
      public $js = [
        'cut.js',
      ];
      public $publishOptions = [
        'forceCopy'=>true,
      ];
   }
```

Comment: Never do this in extension - it is super annoying when 3r-party plugin forces this option. Refreshing assets is a app problem and it should be fixed at app level.

Comment: as i remember, this solution was for plugin developing stage only

Answer (score 2):

I configure the `assetManager::forceCopy=true` in main-local.php for the dev environment like this

```
return [
'components' => [
    ...
    'assetManager' => [
        'forceCopy' => true,
    ]
    ...
],
];
```

Comment: Instead of harcoding the true/false, you can use YII_DEBUG constant, so it is turned off in production

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo rm -rf frontend/web/assets/*
sudo chmod 777 frontend/web/assets
./yii cache/flush-all
```

If this does not work:

```
sudo rm -rf vendor/*
composer install
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [`CClientScript::registerScriptFile`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail) method in my view files:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
    $this->getAssetsBase() . '/js/script.js'
);
```

If I modified script.js, after next page reload I will see all changes

For css files - [`CClientScript::registerCssFile`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCssFile-detail)

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(
    $this->getAssetsBase() . '/css/style.css'
);
```

UPDATE: if you use yii 2.0 beta, you can read some information about changes in mechanic of client helpers here: [`link`](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/665/overcoming-removal-of-client-helpers-e-g-ajaxlink-and-clientscript-in-yii-2-0/)

Comment: that's not what I need

Comment: I found special method publish() in yii2 doc, you can pass in method $options argument with forceCopy => true, and file which you edited will be rewrited in assets folder, link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#publish()-detail

Comment: can you give an example for a valid path?

Answer (score 1):

The AssetManager will create a hash based on the file modification time. The modification time of a directory does not change when any file is changed. 
If you have an AssetBundle that has a directory as `$sourcePath`, the modification time of the directory is used, the hash will not change, and nothing gets copied to the `web/assets` directory.

I suggest overriding `AssetManager::hash()` in a subclass or write a function for `AssetManager::$hashCallback`:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'hashCallback' => function($path) { 
             // if: $path is directory: figure out when files were changed in directory 
             // else: use original hash function in \yii\web\AssetManager
        }
    ], 
]
```

For a sample implementation for finding the max modified date over all asset files in a bundle you could look at this comment by wookie @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php#35779

Note that modification to any asset file will create a new directory in `web/assets`, and regular cleanup will remain necessary. However, browser cache aside, refreshing the page will follow the latest changes.