# Why by every refreshing page, cache reload anew?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've programmed my website by Yii2. When I refresh my website it works like `Ctl + F5`, and all the `font awesome` and all the cache of my site reload again. It look likes I open the page first time.

[Link of my website](http://takhfifgram.com/)

Answer (score 8):

Add, this in your **config** file. According to your need.

> **$linkAssets**
>
> Whether to use symbolic link to publish asset files. Defaults to
>   false, meaning asset files are copied to $basePath. Using symbolic
>   links has the benefit that the published assets will always be
>   consistent with the source assets and there is no copy operation
>   required. This is especially useful during development.

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'linkAssets' => true,
    ], 
]
```

Or

> **$forceCopy**
>
> Whether the directory being published should be copied even if it is
>   found in the target directory. This option is used only when
>   publishing a directory. You may want to set this to be true during the
>   development stage to make sure the published directory is always
>   up-to-date. Do not set this to true on production servers as it will
>   significantly degrade the performance.

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'forceCopy' => true,
    ], 
]
```

For more info, Please click these useful links

1. [Link Assets - Yii2 Asset Manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$linkAssets-detail)
2. [Force Copy - Yii2 Asset Manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$forceCopy-detail)
3. [Assets-Clear-Cache - Yii2 (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819220/yii2-assets-clear-cache)

Or,

As, I am using `Yii2-App-Basic`. So, My Assets are getting created in `ROOT/web/assets folder`. So, I manually hit this action to clear my cache. This is not a good way to clear cache. Even though, it's useful for time being.

This function, I created in **SiteController.php**.

And, I hit URL Like : `MyWebsite.com/site/clear-cache`.

```
<?
public function actionClearCache(){
  $cacheDirPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets';
  if($this->destroy_dir($cacheDirPath, 0)){
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Cache cleared.');
  } 
  return $this->render('some-page');
}

private function destroy_dir($dir, $i = 1) {
  if (!is_dir($dir) || is_link($dir))
    return unlink($dir);
  foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    if (!$this->destroy_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
      chmod($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, 0777);
      if (!$this->destroy_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file))
        return false;
    };
  }
  if($i == 1)return rmdir($dir);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer, but I'm Not asking to the clear cache, even I don't want to clear the cash in every refresh.

Comment: So. What You Want @MohammadAghayari

Comment: My web page automatically reload all the cache in every refresh. but I don't want to reload cache every time.

Comment: That's what I gave you : `linkAssets` & `forcecopy` attributes. @MohammadAghayari

Comment: You might want to add `if ($file == '.' || $file == '..' || $file == '.gitignore')`