# js file path issue YII2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to include my custom js file which is in `C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\bower\backend\assets\js` but console gives me   error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

While other same file have same above directory which is working.
In my appAsset file is under `C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\backend\assets`

```
<?php

namespace backend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main backend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    //public $basePath = '@webroot';
    //public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/backend/';
    public $css = [
            'assets/css/chosen.css',
            'assets/css/style.css',
            'assets/css/font-awesome.min.css',
            'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            //'assets/css/bootstrap.css',
            'assets/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css',
            'assets/css/w3.css',
            'assets/css/jquery-ui.css', 
    ];
    public $js = [
        //'assets/js/jquery.min.js',
        'assets/js/jquery-ui.js',
        'assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
        'assets/js/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js',
        'assets/js/chosen.jquery.js',
        'assets/js/chosen.jquery.js',
        'assets/js/my-custom.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

and my-custom.js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('li.active .treeview').on('click', function(e) {

          $('li.active .treeview-menu').toggleClass("hide");
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The url of the file which is not finding is this

```
http://localhost/yii2/backend/web/assets/c4875c89/assets/js/my-custom.js
```

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm this JS file is really located at the path you provided?

Comment: Yes i have checked @Bizley

Comment: I have uploaded image you can see in image the file @Bizley

Comment: Please update your question with full AppAsset file code. Also `my-custom.js` is 0KB - is it ok?

Comment: can you check now?@Bizley

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are other files copied to `c4875c89` folder in `web/assets`?

Comment: as you said it should work, but to be sure, check if other files from same folders are included, double check names, try to rename file, btw why it is 0kB, delete generated assets, check if other assests from same folder are generated

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this in view file

```
<?php 
   $this->registerJsFile('PATH_TO_FILE');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks of your time. But its wired that why my-custom.js not working while other working. Yeah i have know a little bit  registerJsFile function. I think this is cache issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use RegisterJsFile concept:

You should simply register this js file in your view, e.g. :

```
$this->registerJsFile('@web/js/specific.js');
```

Or your custompath

```
 $this->registerJsFile('PATH_TO_FILELOCATION');
```

Read more :http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#registering-scripts

and

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail

Comment: Thanks I so much appreciate your work. but I have a lot of try but no luck. I have know about the above help. Your help working fine but want to know why not working code. Does YII have cache issue. Thanks @vijay

Comment: yes it may be check this both links might be help you : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819220/yii2-assets-clear-cache


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723515/why-by-every-refreshing-page-cache-reload-anew/37729758#37729758