# How to clear the cache without affecting the cache of the database schema?

Tags: caching, yii2

`Yii::$app->cache->flush()` - clears all caches.
Console command in `yii cache/flush` cache finds nothing.

How to clear the cache without affecting the cache of the database schema?

Comment: You might need to do something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819220/yii2-assets-clear-cache There are a few more questions with similar topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate cache component and its ID is specified in the connection.
'schemaCache' => 'cache2',