# How to Fix Cache JavaScript in Yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

In Yii 2, when I add a few code rows to my JavaScript file, that has a cache, it will not accept my additional code to the JavaScript file.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 assets clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819220/yii2-assets-clear-cache)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [forceCopy](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$forceCopy-detail) option in asset manager under components :

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'forceCopy' => true,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did it by chanding version in asset file where i include this js:

```
 public $js = [
    'js/script.js?0.0.1',
];
```